# Running into this ERROR when I try to migrate a workbench to an Azure MySQL server

Tags: mysql-workbench, azure-mysql-database, libmysqlclient

```
dyld[55763]: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmysqlclient.dylib
Referenced from: <75D8AA6C-EE86-3CFC-9881-04C24191CAD3> /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/wbcopytables
Reason: tried: '/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmysqlclient.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
ERROR: Determine number of rows to copy: Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code -6
Failed
```

[image: Picture of the Workbench migration ERROR]

I am trying to migrate a database through MySQLWorkBench to a MySQL server in Azure but run into this problem. Any input, assistance, and direction is greatly appreaciated.I am using the migration wizard in WorkBench and get all the way to Bulk Data Transfer step (pretty much the final step) but get this error.

I am on Mac.

Thanks!

I am trying to connect to my remote db from WorkBench and run from there my .sql script to create the table in my new remote db.